# How should we react whenever we encounter ideas that we disagree with?

Tags: discussion, ideologies

I am not trying to start an argument with this.  I am also not trying to prove anyone wrong.  I just want everyone to be on the same page.

In the comments following [this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1830/does-rioting-impair-the-economy), there are some remarks that are at least somewhat offensive toward religious academic institutions, beliefs held by certain religious groups, and the author of the article referenced in the original question.  (I am not making a value judgment on the comments themselves; rather, I am judging the way the comments were made.)

I understand that there will be a lot of disagreement in the areas of economics and religion and we shouldn't expect everyone to agree.  So, that being said, how should we react whenever we encounter ideas that we disagree with?

**Edit**
The more offensive post (the one with a derivation of the "s" word) against religious academic institutions and the author of the linked article has been removed.  But the other issues remain in the remaining comments.

Comment: I'm curious to know what others think about the particular situation in the link you provide. This will be helpful in setting a precedent for how to deal with issues like this.

Comment: The comments are way off topic and should be deleted.  The question is also way off topic and should be deleted.  I can imagine ways to make this question interesting, e.g. "In calculating the cost of a riot --- or a hurricane --- how should we include changes in land values in neighboring areas?".  But no interesting form of the question will mention Ferguson specifically,  because all of the interesting questions are far more general than that.

Comment: I think the use of crude language (in the comment now deleted) is not appropriate for the site. But I have no qualms with the general sentiment expressed in that comment. I think it is fair enough to question whether ideas or statements are supported by evidence or make logical sense. I think it is also fair to call for special scrutiny of ideas that come from sources that have shown themselves to be unreliable in the past.

Comment: As far as economics vs religion (or ideology, or any other non-substantiated thought) is concerned: this is an economics site. We should respect the beliefs as others, but those beliefs have no place polluting the scientific discussion on this site. Reason and evidence should be welcome here, superstition should not.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it away. If you "believe" in something - keep it to your self - it has nothing to do on this site. Be that political or religious views.

As Ubiquitous puts it very elegantly in a comment

> "Reason and evidence should be welcome here, superstition should not."